# What Does It Mean When DVD-RW Drives Only Read CDs?

Tags: dvd, optical-drive

So, I have a really strange hardware problem with a laptop optical drive where it can read any CD, but no DVD (I am sure this is not a region encoding issue, despite being a French-bought laptop).

The laptop in question is the [Asus A6J](http://www.asus.com/Search.aspx?SearchKey=a6j).  The laptop is using the most current BIOS version, and I updated the drive, the [TSSTCorp L632D](http://www.google.com/search?q=tsstcorp+l632d&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) that originally shipped with the laptop with [the most recent manufacturer firmware](http://backfire.rpc1.org/tsstcorp/index.php?path=TS-L632D/)  (when I was asked to troubleshoot, *it was still the default I presume from Asus and was in the same state*, that did not work of course).

It appears to have successfully flashed, so I am fairly certain that is not the issue.

No matter what I have tried, the drive will correctly read CD disks.  Any DVD, regardless of region, content, etc. is never read.

In Windows or Linux or BSD, I do not see anything at all.  Does anyone know how this could be possible?  Does that mean there is a hardware disparity that the part able to read DVDs is broken and the CD reading components are functional?

The drive knows it is worthy of reading DVDs, according to [Nero InfoTool](http://www.nero.com/ena/support-nero6-tools-utilities.html). Thoughts?

Comment: I know you said ANY dvd but...  what happens when you put a blank one in and try to burn files onto it?

Comment: I did not try that, but that is only because I did not have one handy.  Again, I want to know if this is a foregone conclusion hardware failure or I fscked something up.

Comment: Boot back into Linux, open a root terminal, enter 'tail -f /var/log/kern.log', and then try to view files on the DVD.  The output of the command may give you some clues.

Comment: @Ultrasawblade I guess that is a good point.  I will try this over the weekend and let you know; it is not one of my own computers.

Comment: The last DVD-RW drive I had that did that wound up being a defective drive, lucky for me it was under warranty from Dell, about 8 months old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optical drives use different lasers to read DVDs vs. CDs.  It's entirely possible for one part to break and not the other.  That's almost certainly what happened to you -- the drive is (partially) broken.  Buy a replacement drive, or RMA if under warranty.

Comment: Inevitably had to face the facts. Thanks and sorry for the way late reply.