# PC DVD player recognize only CDs?

Tags: dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Does It Mean When DVD-RW Drives Only Read CDs?](https://superuser.com/questions/241474/what-does-it-mean-when-dvd-rw-drives-only-read-cds)

Having a problem with my PC DVD player. HP desktop PC running Windows 7 , the DVD recognizes only CDs and play them doesn't recognize all DVD's (data, games, movies).

HP online support tried to reinstall the drivers with no success.

Comment: Double check you've installed the correct driver.

Comment: How old is the player?  Double check that it is actually a DVD player?  ;-)  Can you provide a model number?

Comment: Does your system read *any* DVDs at all?  Any DVD drive manufactured within at least the past 5 years (probably longer) is going to be able to read all the major formats (+R/W, -R/W, -RAM)

Comment: Agreeing with afrazier, please post the model number.  I'd give even odds you have a CD-RW drive there.

Answer (score 1):

There are several standards for DVDs (e.g. DVD-R vs. DVD+R), make sure your player is compatible with the media.